# Print out nested list items in R

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply

I have a nested list and would like to print out certain elements.

A sample dput below:

```
list(structure(list(publisherId = 111, categoryId = 42281, levelId = 462, 
    subcategoryIdList = list(42284), exerciseIdList = list(c(495048, 
    495047, 495043, 495044, 495045, 495046, 495049, 495050)), 
    knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(publisherId = 111, categoryId = 41394, levelId = 459, 
        subcategoryIdList = list(41395), exerciseIdList = list(
            c(473272, 473270, 473269, 473262, 473261, 465453, 
            465452)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))
```

So the list contains another set of lists, which then contains another set of lists.

I am able to get the values for a single nested list using the mentioned below code:

```
t <- myd1[[1]][[5]]
for (i in t) {
  print(i)
}
```

But I do not know, how to build another for loop around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the purrr package ([cheat sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/purrr.pdf)). It contains many useful functions for working with lists.

If you want to extract every fifth element of each sub-list, just use

```
map(list_name, 5)
```

Lets take your data and apply it:

```
test_ls <- list(structure(list(publisherId = 111, categoryId = 42281, levelId = 462, 
                    subcategoryIdList = list(42284), exerciseIdList = list(c(495048, 
                                                                             495047, 495043, 495044, 495045, 495046, 495049, 495050)), 
                    knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
     structure(list(publisherId = 111, categoryId = 41394, levelId = 459, 
                    subcategoryIdList = list(41395), exerciseIdList = list(
                      c(473272, 473270, 473269, 473262, 473261, 465453, 
                        465452)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))

map(test_ls, 5)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 495048 495047 495043 495044 495045 495046 495049 495050


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 473272 473270 473269 473262 473261 465453 465452
```

If it is a named list, as in your case, you can also subset by name:

```
map(test_ls, "exerciseIdList")
```

If you want to remove one level of hierarchy from the new sub-lists use:

```
map(test_ls, 5) %>% flatten
[[1]]
[1] 495048 495047 495043 495044 495045 495046 495049 495050

[[2]]
[1] 473272 473270 473269 473262 473261 465453 465452
```

Comment: Thank you @TimTeaFan. I was not aware of the purr package. This works perfectly fine. Once again, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
t <- myd1[[1]][[5]]
for (i in t) {
  for (j in i) {
     print(j)
  }  
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but I would need to manually change the selected list element, like for example: `t <- myd1[[3]][[5]]
for (i in t) {
  for (j in i) {
    print(j)
  }  
}` Is there a way to replace this step ?

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to print all elements of the list you might try this:

```r
for (i in seq_along(1:length(myd1))){
  for(j in seq_along(1: length(myd1[[1]]))){
    print(unlist(myd1[[i]][[j]]))  
  }
}
# [1] 111
# [1] 42281
# [1] 462
# [1] 42284
# [1] 495048 495047 495043 495044 495045 495046 495049 495050
# NULL
# [1] 111
# [1] 41394
# [1] 459
# [1] 41395
# [1] 473272 473270 473269 473262 473261 465453 465452
# NULL
```

## Update

To get the `fifth` element of the list `myd1`, you can do the following:

```r
for (i in seq_along(1:length(myd1))){
  for(j in seq(1)){
    print(unlist(myd1[[i]][[j,(length(myd1[[i]])-1)]]))
  }
}
#Output
#[1] 495048 495047 495043 495044 495045 495046 495049 495050
#[1] 473272 473270 473269 473262 473261 465453 465452
```

If you need explanation, let me know.

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly fine for the whole components, but how would it work to get only the fifth element of this list, so the vector of numbers in your answer above c(495048,495047,495043...) ? I am running in an error performing this kind of code `test <- for (j in myd1) {
  for (i in j) {
    print([[i]][[5]])
  }
}`

Comment: @user12121022, see my update, if you want to get the fifth element of the list `(myd1)`.